# Blank pixels results in some area random forest classification

Tags: google-earth-engine

[image: random forest classification results]

I tried RF Classification but the results of the classification show some blank areas or pixels like this.
I am a beginner and not sure what goes wrong.

PS. I did try the code a few times on other location and never find this issue.

(I revised the code; I realize I didn't copy it well before. Still encounter the same issue)

```
     //// LANDCOVER CLASSIFICATION MAP 2014

// Load Landsat8 and Select Year 2014
var LS = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2");

var LS2014= LS.filterDate('2014-01-01', 
                            '2014-12-31');

// Color Pallete
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes')

// Function for cloudmask 
var cloudMask = function(image){
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var qaMask0 = qaMask.bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2))
  .eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(qaMask0);
};

// Load Target Area Boundary
var site = ee.FeatureCollection("users/targetarea");
Map.centerObject(site,13);
Map.addLayer(site,{ 
            },"site",true,0.7);

//ndvi
var ndvi_calc = function(i){
  var red = i.select('SR_B4').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var nir = i.select('SR_B5').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var ndvi = (nir.subtract(red))
                  .divide(nir.add(red))
                  .rename('ndvi');
  return i.addBands(ndvi);
};
var NDVI2014 = LS2014
                    .map(cloudMask)
                    .map(ndvi_calc)
                    .median();

var NDVI2014site = NDVI2014.clip(site)

Map.addLayer(NDVI2014site,{
  bands:['ndvi'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette:palettes.cmocean.Speed[7]
},
'NDVI 2014',
false);

Map.addLayer(NDVI2014site,{
  bands:['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 2000,
  max: 20000
},
'LS 2014',
false);


//LAND CLASSIFICATION PROCESS
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection([Water,Forest,Shrubs,Urban])
                    .flatten();

var predictionBands = ['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5',
                      'SR_B6','SR_B7','ST_B10','ndvi'];


var LS_with_pts = NDVI2014site
                      .select(predictionBands)
                      .sampleRegions({
                        collection: pts,
                        properties: ['class'],
                        scale: 30
                      })

print(LS_with_pts);

var trainingTesting = LS_with_pts.randomColumn();
var trainingSet = trainingTesting.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random', 0.7));
var testingSet = trainingTesting.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random', 0.7));
print(testingSet)

//RandomRorests
var RFclassifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train(
  {
    features: trainingSet,
    classProperty: 'class',
    inputProperties: predictionBands
  })

var RFclassified = NDVI2014site
                        .select(predictionBands)
                        .classify(RFclassifier);

Map.addLayer(RFclassified, {
  min:0, max:3, palette: ['7dc6d5', // water
                          '32673f', // forest
                          'b7e160', // shrubs
                          '903c35']}, // urban
                  'classification', true) ;


var test = testingSet.classify(RFclassifier);
var confusionMatrix = test.errorMatrix('class', 'classification');
print('Testing confusion matrix', confusionMatrix);
print('Testing Overall acuracy', confusionMatrix.accuracy());

print('Procuders accuracy', confusionMatrix.producersAccuracy());
print('Users accuracy', confusionMatrix.consumersAccuracy());
```

Comment: You don't include your `cloudMask` function in your code, but I would guess that is what is causing the blank areas by masking out pixels deemed cloudy.

Comment: Thank you for response. I realize I didn't properly copy the code. Here is the revised version. I did include the `cloudMask` function. But it wont do